# Are there any alternatives to pylibdmtx for reading data matrix

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, datamatrix

I am looking for a decoder that can read and decode Data matrix in python. I came across **pylibdmtx** that works but it is slow. Are there any alternatives? Any work in neural networks that can help me?

```
from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import decode
from PIL import Image
decode(Image.open('matrix.png'))
```

This takes *~2sec* to process a png with size *250x250px*.